# Save the state of the Sort before leaving Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I use a jquery plugin to sort my html table. It works well but I want to be able to "save my sort" after leaving the page and returning. if I leave the page and return - the sort starts over again.

I want to maintain the state of the sort - so when I return - it is entact how I left it...

Here is a working example...
https://rawgit.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin/master/examples/basic.html

here is the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
      <title>Stupid jQuery table sort</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../stupidtable.js?dev"></script>
      <script>
        $(function(){
            $("table").stupidtable();
        });
      </script>
      <style type="text/css">
        table {
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
          padding: 5px 10px;
          border: 1px solid #999;
        }
        th {
          background-color: #eee;
        }
        th[data-sort]{
          cursor:pointer;
        }
        tr.awesome{
          color: red;
        }
      </style>
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>

      <h1>Stupid jQuery table sort!</h1>

      <p>This example shows how a sortable table can be implemented with very little configuration. Simply specify the data type on a <code>&lt;th&gt;</code> element using the <code>data-sort</code> attribute, and the plugin handles the rest.</p>

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th data-sort="int">int</th>
            <th data-sort="float">float</th>
            <th data-sort="string">string</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>-.18</td>
            <td>banana</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="awesome">
            <td>95</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>coke</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>-152.5</td>
            <td>apple</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-53</td>
            <td>88.5</td>
            <td>zebra</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>195</td>
            <td>-858</td>
            <td>orange</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: use `localStorage`?

Answer (score 0):

The **[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** API is easy to use and can persist data between user sessions.

To store an item:  `localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');`

And, to retreive an item: `localStorage.getItem('myCat');`

Keep in mind that all data is stored as strings.

Comment: localstorage is not a good option as I am involved on a server used by many applications. Also, it would be nice to have a specific solution to my issue and not broad answers about cats....

Comment: @Ronald The fact that there are many applications running on your server really has no bearing on the viability of using `localStorage`. Also, I'm sorry that you don't like the solution to your problem with a link to its documentation and a super easy to understand example.  Did you want me to come over to your house, sit at your workstation and upload the solution to your server for you as well?